# Simple four liner: what am I?

Tags: riddle

I have legs and I sometimes move

Some without legs put me to use.

I'm known to have been musical, my favorite type is rock.

If you've been acting badly, you're in for quite a shock.

*What am I?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are

> a chair

I have legs

> Most chairs have four legs

and I sometimes move / Some without legs put me to use.

> a wheelchair

I'm known to have been musical,

> Musical chairs is a popular children's game

my favorite type is rock.

> Who doesn't love a rocking chair?

If you've been acting badly, you're in for quite a shock.

> the Electric Chair